# What is CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude equivalent in Obj-C

Tags: swift, objective-c, cgfloat

What is the equivalent of `CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude` equivalent in Objective-C?
I googled but could not find any answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cgfloat/1845210-leastnonzeromagnitude) of `leastNonzeroMagnitude` says:

> Compares less than or equal to all positive numbers, but greater than zero. If the target supports subnormal values, this is smaller than `leastNormalMagnitude`; otherwise they are equal.

So the value of this also depends on "if the target supports subnormal values". Looking at the [implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/FloatingPointTypes.swift.gyb#L524), we can see:

```
public static var leastNonzeroMagnitude: ${Self} {
#if arch(arm)
  // On 32b arm, the default FPCR has subnormals flushed to zero.
  return leastNormalMagnitude
#else
  return leastNormalMagnitude * ulpOfOne
#endif
}
```

It turns out that ARM is the target that doesn't "support subnormal values". :)

If you translate the two branches into Objective-C separately, it would be:

```
CGFLOAT_MIN
```

and

```
CGFLOAT_MIN * CGFLOAT_EPSILON
```

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn't provide an Objective-C constant equivalent to `CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude`.

Apple does provide `CGFLOAT_MIN`, which is the smallest positive **normal** nonzero value. It's equivalent to `CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude`. This is 2.225073858507201e-308 on systems with 64-bit `CGFloat`.

There are constants (specified by the C11 standard) for the smallest positive non-zero `float` and `double`, including subnormals: `FLT_TRUE_MIN` is 1.401298e-45 and `DBL_TRUE_MIN` is 4.940656458412465e-324.

Apple provides a constant `CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE` which is 1 if `CGFloat` is `double` and zero if it is `float`. So you can check that to define your own `CGFLOAT_TRUE_MIN`. You should also guard against Apple adding its own definition in the future.

```
#ifndef CGFLOAT_TRUE_MIN
#if CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE
#define CGFLOAT_TRUE_MIN DBL_TRUE_MIN
#else
#define CGFLOAT_TRUE_MIN FLT_TRUE_MIN
#endif
#endif
```

But the only supported platform that still uses 32-bit `CGFloat` is watchOS, and its unlikely that you're targeting watchOS if you're using Objective-C. If you are only targeting 64-bit versions of iOS/macOS/tvOS, you can simplify the definition:

```
#ifndef CGFLOAT_TRUE_MIN
#define CGFLOAT_TRUE_MIN DBL_TRUE_MIN
#endif
```